# Specifying Maven memory parameter without setting MAVEN_OPTS environment variable

Tags: maven, environment-variables

I was wondering if it is possible to specify Maven memory boundaries with a syntax similar to:

```
mvn -Dtest=FooTest -DXmx=512M clean test
```

I tried a couple of variations till now, unsuccessfully.
I am aware of MAVEN_OPTS environment variable, but I would like to avoid that.

Related to the above question, it would be nice to know if there is the possibility to specify the memory behavior of the **surefire** plugin in a similar manner, so that it forks the jvm using the overridden memory amount (eventually overriding the `<argLine>` parameter in the pom plugin configuration, if present)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can configure the surefire-plugin to use more memory. Take a look on
[Strange Maven out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024270/strange-maven-out-of-memory-error/4032894#4032894).

**Update**: 
If you would like to set the parameter from command-line take a look on {{mvn.bat}} (or {{mvn}} shell script) in your maven installation directory. It uses with additional options specified in command line.

Next possibility is to set surefire-plugin and use properties specified in command-line, e.g. `mvn ... -Dram=512`

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <argLine>-Xms${ram}m -Xmx${ram}m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: hello amra, thanks for your reply. As mentioned in my post, I am interested in specifying memory setting as arguments to the mvn command. Both for mvn itself, or i.e. the surfire plugin, if possible. Cheers

Answer (score 78):

To specify the max memory (not via MAVEN_OPTS as originally requested) you can do the following:

```
mvn clean install -DargLine="-Xmx1524m"
```

Comment: This is actually not true. If you use a [jvisualvm](https://visualvm.java.net/), that you even already have in your JDK (under bin directory), you will see that the argument is not applied on the JVM, but as a system property argLine=-Xmx1524m .

Comment: This is not true, `argLine` only affects a forked process created for running tests (Surefire), not the actual process used to do compilation etc. Whereas `MAVEN_OPTS` affects everything.

Answer (score 5):

Since Maven 3.3.1 a default can also be specified in `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config`

It is documented here: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html#JVM_and_Command_Line_Options

Comment: This method works for setting the JPDA for debugging. -DargLine will not enable debugging.