# Is there a way to pass JVM args via command line to Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Maven Jetty plugin - how to control VM arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007192/maven-jetty-plugin-how-to-control-vm-arguments)

In particular, I want to do something like this:

```
mvn -DjvmArgs="-Xmx2000m -Xms1000m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" jetty:run -Pmyprofile
```

Oh, and I would like to do this without having to modify the pom files or set any environment variables.. etc

Comment: you have to set the MAVEN_OPTS enviroment variable, but that can be done on the command line: `MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2000m" mvn jetty:run`

Comment: A little late, but you can use the -DargLine switch rather than using a global value. Full example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527789/specifying-maven-memory-parameter-without-setting-maven-opts-environment-variabl/30441186#30441186)

Comment: It's never too late!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68069089/5611377

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I think `MAVEN_OPTS` would be most appropriate for you. See here: http://maven.apache.org/configure.html

In Unix:

> Add the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable to specify JVM properties, e.g. `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"`. This environment variable can be used to supply extra options to Maven.

In Win, you need to set environment variable via the dialogue box

> Add ... environment variable by opening up the system properties (`WinKey + Pause`),...  In the same dialog, add the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable in the user variables to specify JVM properties, e.g. the value `-Xms256m -Xmx512m`. This environment variable can be used to supply extra options to Maven.

Comment: Is there a way to configure JVM argument in pom file?

Comment: @nanosoft No, as this would be to late (the JVM would have been started already). But [since Maven 3.3.1](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html#JVM_and_Command_Line_Options) you can create a `.mvn/jvm.config` file with just the options in it.

Comment: is it possible to give it as runtime args

Comment: `WinKey + Pause` how have I never learnt this before?! Very useful

Comment: Tried this from a bash script but got: `MAVEN_OPTS: readonly variable`

Comment: @MartinHöller `.mvn/jvm.config` only works during the build or when the fork count is zero (use `-DforkCount=0` in command line) beauce a forked VM might be used during the tests.

Comment: I can't make maven use my system certificates on macOS: I'm adding "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=KeychainStore" to .mvn/jvm.config without success. Option is from general JVM answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280578/how-to-set-up-java-vm-to-use-the-root-certificates-truststore-handled-by-mac-o

Comment: I don't have a pause key on my keyboard.