# Maven and properties for slf4j simplelogger

Tags: maven, logging, slf4j

I don't understand some behavior when I run:

```
mvn -V clean -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=true
```

I get:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12- 14T18:29:23+01:00)
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
...
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, it looks like property `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName` is not recognized by slf4j

When I change this property in `conf/logging/simplelogger.properties` I get:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00)
Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation
...
[main] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[main] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I have what I expected.

Also `mvn help:system -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=true` says that property is set.

What I do wrong?

I would like to use cli for setting properties for sl4j. I wouldn't like to change maven internal configuration file.

Comment: try setting this in `MAVEN_OPTS`, `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=true"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-D` [option](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) to `mvn` sets the argument as a [maven property](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html). org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName is a [Java system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). Maven properties include Java system properties, but not vice versa.

The easiest way to pass a java system property to a library used by maven (e.g.  slf4j) is to add it to the [MAVEN_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525288/is-there-a-way-to-pass-jvm-args-via-command-line-to-maven) environment variable.