# Unable to open debugger port for Spring boot debug with intelliJIdea

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea

I want to debug a Spring boot application with IntelliJ. I'm using windows 10. 
when I run my spring boot project with following command it works fine. But debugging not working.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=dev -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

And then I make a remote debugger with intelliJ as follows.

[image]

but when I click the debug button intelliJ shows following message.

> Error running 'RemoteDeBugger': Unable to open debugger port
>   (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused:
>   connect

What is the reason for above behavior and how to do debugging correctly.

Comment: Try using some other port number, see if the app is listening for the debugger connection on the specified port using TcpView.

Comment: I think no. Seems even though I started the application in debug mood it doesn't started in debug mode. I tried with deference port numbers

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50677882/104891?

Answer (score 12):

> What is the reason for above behavior?

You have this error because your remote debugger is looking to a JVM listening to the port 5005.

> how to do debugging correctly?

You have to run such a JVM first, i mean with the port 5005. Well, to do it, you already have the answer:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

or

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

Using `agentlib:jwdp` is better as specified from the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html)

> From 5.0 onwards the -agentlib:jdwp option is used to load and specify
>   options to the JDWP agent. For releases prior to 5.0, the -Xdebug and
>   -Xrunjdwp options are used (the 5.0 implementation also supports the -Xdebug and -Xrunjdwp options but the newer -agentlib:jdwp option is preferable as the JDWP agent in 5.0 uses the JVMTI interface to the VM
>   rather than the older JVMDI interface).

After everything started up successfully, you can then launch your configured remote debugger by clicking on **debug**.

Make sure you use the same port than the one used for running the app.

You will be at that time good to start analyzing your code from breakpoints.

Comment: don't know why it has been down voted when the answer is perfectly addressing the question. Down voting without giving proper reason is against the good will of this community.

Comment: Finally, something that works. The -Drun.profiles=dev version is the one I tried and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In newest versions of IntelliJ IDEA just choose "Remote" option in configurations and fill you host. Then copy JVM command line arguments to remote JVM like it described in [Philippe Simo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5615357/philippe-simo)'s answer.
[image]