# Debug mode with maven and eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, debugging

when I run a spring-boot application with this command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```

and then I try to connect in debug mode with eclipse, I obtain the error:

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect
```

Why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: See if this works for you:[Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975384/eclipse-error-failed-to-connect-to-remote-vm).

Comment: Perhaps the top answer or others to [`Maven spring boot run debug with arguments`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51513723/1744774) helps: "_The parameter name has to be prefixed with `spring-boot.` as in `-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArgument`_"

Comment: With parameter name -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArgument it works. Thx