# Springboot, use application-{profile}.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created 2 files under src/main/resources:

- application.properties
- application-local.properties

The first one has properties that take values from env variables, while the latter has fixed values.

According to specific [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config), I've launched spring boot in such way:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

However no effects are produced and application-local.properties seems to be ignored.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, if you're running with the spring-boot plugin, you have to pass the profile with `-Dspring-boot.run.profiles`, try

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this, it worked for me!**

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=something"
```

**Check if this article throws some light !**

[Maven spring boot run debug with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217949/maven-spring-boot-run-debug-with-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

In the **same path** as the existing **application.properties** file, you can create 2 environment files:

```
application-local.properties
application-server.properties
```

to call local you can run this command:

```
$ java –jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local app.jar
```

or, you can directly call it in the application.properties file:

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```