# How to run junit tests by maven in terminal with JVM arguments

Tags: java, maven, junit

As mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873995/run-a-single-test-method-with-maven) we can run test methods using,

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#xyz test
```

But I need to set some JVM arguments before run the test case. Like I need to use

`-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=mypolicy.policy`

How can I tell maven to consider those when running a test case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to pass jvm args via command line to maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525288/is-there-a-way-to-pass-jvm-args-via-command-line-to-maven)

Comment: @Eomm so how can we use that to pass VM args when running test cases

Comment: As suggested, you could use an envitoment variable called MAVEN_OPTS  http://maven.apache.org/configure.html

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html.

Comment: the surefire plugin creates its own process. You can use -DargLine="" to pass additional arguments to that new process: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine

Answer (score 13):

Two possible solutions:

First, if your JVM arguments are applicable to all tests, you can add such information as a configuration item for Surefire as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=mypolicy.policy</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Second, if such JVM arguments are to be applied on a test-by-test basis, they can be specified on the command line as follows:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestCircle#xyz test -DargLine="-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=mypolicy.policy"
```