# Failed Maven build remains stuck when using jmx

Tags: java, maven, port, jmx

I'm using (almost) latest Intellij Ultimate 2022.1.1 (same with latest VS Code) with JDK 8 and maven 3.6.3 (can't upgrade)

When executing Maven build (as compile/package) and it fails (for example compilation error)

I can't rerun because port 1100 is still used by a `java.exe` process I must kill manually

As a work around I kill process in command line dynamically

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :1100') DO TaskKill.exe /F /PID %P
```

jps output :

```
RMI Registry not available at 11808:1099
Exception creating connection to: 11808; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
```

**EDIT **

Problem was due to environment variable `MAVEN_OPTS` jmxremote.port 1100 used for [activate JMX for JConsole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856881/how-to-activate-jmx-on-my-jvm-for-access-with-jconsole)

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1100
```

Comment: Does your build work in plain command line? Why is the port 1100 used by a java process? By which one?

Comment: Which process executes the maven build? You means from inside IntelliJ? Which version of IntelliJ do you use? Which version of Maven, JDK etc. do you use? Furthermore the error message would also be helpful...

Comment: Your maven build should by default not require any network port.  Sounds like there are tests running during the build.

Comment: Why do you use an old Maven version? 3.6.3 ??? In IntelliJ 2022.1.1 is by default Maven 3.8.1... furthermore and yes no port should be used by default... It sounds like one of your tests is using a port? Do you have spring boot tests via WebMVC or alike?

Comment: Have a closer look at where it is stuck then.  You can use `jps` at the command line to locate old processes you though about

Comment: Or simply just reboot your machine.

Comment: Check what process occupies the `1100` port and kill this process. Check for Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48198/2000323 Check for Linux: https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/

Comment: @Andrey java.exe process called from Intellij  I can kill, but why should I kill process every build

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen added bounty and more details to question

Comment: @Andrey added bounty and more details to question, I can kill process, but I prefer to avoid keeping hanging processes

Comment: @khmarbaise bounty and more details to question, it happen also on compiling, notice I'm using remote url repository

Comment: @khmarbaise Maven 3.6 and older still allows an access to a plugin reporsitory with http. In Maven 3.7 and higher this protocol is blocked by default. But it exists an official workaround for this case.

Comment: @Reporter good catch we are using http to connect to our repository

Comment: @Reporter I know that there is blocking access to http repository which is introduced in Maven 3.8.1 (https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html) apart from that Maven 3.7 does not exist...

Comment: `RMI Registry not available at 11808:1099` - this is very very wierd.  Why is "11808" a host  name here?

Comment: And _why_ do you modify your hosts file?  What else has happened to it?

Comment: To answer the question "How can I automatically close the process?": You can use either `exec-maven-plugin` or `maven-antrun-plugin` to run a script that closes the process. However the other comment are correct in that its weird it's hanging in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure that you need attach jConsole to the maven process and not to the program compiled by maven?

Comment: @Nick Initially I tried to attach it while executing tests using maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij starts maven background process to import dependencies (and other things) and doesn't close it for faster re-run. This background process uses `MAVEN_OPTS` just like normal maven process and listens port preventing other maven processes from starting

Remove global `MAVEN_OPTS` and set `-D*.jmxremote.*` perameters only for the required process

- You can set perameters in intellij Run/Debug Configuration
- When run from terminal: `export MAVEN_OPTS="" && mvn package`
- For run tests try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41576365/6066470)

Comment: So solution is to add to `argLine`  for adding jmx to maven test