# Error packaging a Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5 app from the command line

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 2.0.0.M5 app. that use quartz, that I create using Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.9.0.RELEASE

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

but I have an error building it, but I don't have any clue where the error comes from when I run the command `mvn clean package` from the command line

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project telefonicaUtils: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/lopes/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/telefonicaUtils/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /Users/lopes/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/telefonicaUtils && /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -jar /Users/lopes/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/telefonicaUtils/target/surefire/surefirebooter5299870482700724545.jar /Users/lopes/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/telefonicaUtils/target/surefire 2017-10-27T11-43-54_756-jvmRun1 surefire7195528782456466016tmp surefire_03680109476808337424tmp
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /Users/lopes/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/telefonicaUtils && /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -jar /Users/lopes/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/telefonicaUtils/target/surefire/surefirebooter5299870482700724545.jar /Users/lopes/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/telefonicaUtils/target/surefire 2017-10-27T11-43-54_756-jvmRun1 surefire7195528782456466016tmp surefire_03680109476808337424tmp
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:686)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:535)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:280)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1124)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

and the only test I have in the app. is this one:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TelefonicaUtilsApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

but doing only `mvn clean` Its working fine

I also tried `mvn clean install -XX:-UseLoopPredicate` with this error:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'X' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/lopes/.m2/repository), spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot), spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'X' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/lopes/.m2/repository), spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot), spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:93)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I also tried to add this in the pom.xml with the same error

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and this is the java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: very old JVM version...144 is the most recent and the next version (162 ear access is announced)...Have you checked to use the previous version of maven-surefire-plugin (2.19.1)...

Comment: java version updated to 1.8.0_151

Comment: @khmarbaise, please converto to answer

Comment: @enLopes can you show full maven pom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue by logs doesn't seem to be related to the `maven-surefire-plugin`. Though from the logs(`jdk1.8.0_77`) and the java version explicitly specified(`1.8.0_151`) there seems to be an inconsistency there.

You should update the maven configurations of your machine to make use of the latest java version as well.

---

Just to add to the information, the command `mvn clean` could execute normally since it does not involve compiling/executing the code.

From the [Maven - Introduction to the lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

> the clean lifecycle handles project cleaning

which essentially

> remove all files generated by the previous build

---

The command next `mvn clean install -XX:-UseLoopPredicate` executed, *FAILS*, since there is no such argument flag as `-XX` on maven command line. You should instead take a look at [Is there a way to pass jvm args via command line to maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525288/is-there-a-way-to-pass-jvm-args-via-command-line-to-maven) for what seems to be your purpose of trial there.