# Setting properties via Maven command line

Tags: java, maven, properties, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm confused about the correct way to set a property for some unit tests via the command line when using Maven. There are a number of questions (e.g. [Specifying Maven memory parameter without setting MAVEN_OPTS environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7527789/820657), [Is there a way to pass jvm args via command line to maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12525288/820657), [How to set JVM parameters for Junit Unit Tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7579776/820657)) that touch on this subject but none have the answer I'm looking for.

I want to set the property `java.util.logging.config.class` to some value but I don't want to set the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable.

I can configure the surefire plugin in my pom file with the property:

```xml
<argLine>-Djava.util.logging.config.class=someClass</argLine>
```

so that it is set every time the test phase is run.

However, if I remove the setting from the pom file and add the following to the command line:

```
mvn package -DargLine="java.util.logging.config.class=someClass"
```

then the following error in the test phase is reported and the build fails:

> Error: Could not find or load main class java.util.logging.config.class=someClass

If I run the following from the command line:

```
mvn package -Djava.util.logging.config.class=someClass
```

then the following error is reported at the beginning of the build but the build and tests are successful:

> Logging configuration class "someClass" failed
>       java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: someClass

I don't really understand the behaviour. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you should have

```
mvn package -DargLine="-Djava.util.logging.config.class=someClass"
```

Notice the addition of `-D` inside the `argLine`.

Let's explain why. [`argLine`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine) is indeed an attribute of the [`maven-surefire-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) with the corresponding user property `argLine`. This means that you can set this property directly on the command line with `-DargLine`. But then, the value of that property is `-Djava.util.logging.config.class=someClass`. This is exactly what you had when you configured the plugin in the POM directly with

```xml
<argLine>-Djava.util.logging.config.class=someClass</argLine>
```

---

Additionally, when you call

```
mvn package -Djava.util.logging.config.class=someClass
```

then you are not setting the `argLine` property. You are adding a system property.

Answer (score 1):

### Regarding your approach to configuring tests

If you want to pass in configuration to your tests, use for example a file in src/test/resources/myTestConfig.xml. Or use the enhanced features of [Test-ng](http://testng.org/). Your tests will have no value on the centralized build server, or those who want to run/test your code, where config values can't be changed (easily).

The recommended usage of command-line arguments for Maven is for configuring the Maven plugins, build environment and Java config for the build. 
Use as little features, config and plugins as possible. Or you'll face a ton of issues down the line, and the tweak-all-you-want-A-standardized-build-doesn't-mean-sh*t-for-me-[Gradle](http://gradle.org/) will feel more comfortable.

Comment: Wouldn't a config file be overkill here? I just want to set the `java.util.logging.config.class` property to control the logging output from a 3rd party library that my application depends on.

Comment: If a command-line argument is for "just getting stuff to work on your computer", go for it. But if that code is intended to run somewhere else; you'll have to supply pretty detailed instructions for adding the command line options. Even placing such config in the pom is a smell. I've not solved this particular problem before, but a logging-shim like [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org) might lift the problems out of heterogenous logging frameworks.