# how to pass aws environment variable from command prompt in maven

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, environment-variables

I have some AWS features related test in a maven project which I would like to run with command prompt. Below is the workflow to run these test:

1. I hit a powershell file to generate aws credential
2. I add them in edit configuration (When run through intelij)
3. I run

Same steps when I replicated with a batch file, I created batch file with following content:

```
powershell "D:/Users/dosqauser/awscred.ps1"
cd "D:/Users/UserName/Documents/API_Automation/api-automation/"
mvn -DargLine="AWS_PROFILE=env-fullaccess" test
```

This is not setting the credential as I am getting following error:

```
aws.doesBucketExist(bucketName), Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain.
```

I tried with this as well after reading some answers :

```
export AWS_PROFILE=env-fullaccess
mvn test
unset AWS_PROFILE
```

but it also didn't work.

Comment: This maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716689/9095551

Comment: I am trying to use a key-value pair that generates in the first step of the batch file. powershell "D:/Users/dosqauser/awscred.ps1" while in the mentioned answer, he/she is using a class file