# Using JUnit Test is OK,but Using maven test is not ok,

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, junit, spring-data-jpa

platform :eclipse neon+springmvc+jpa+maven
    springframework 4.3 
when I use JUnit Test ,code is ok, console show the right result, the console show details:

```
19:01:43.491 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@71c8becc, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@19d37183, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1a0dcaa, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@3bd40a57, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@fdefd3f, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@d83da2e]
19:01:43.504 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@78e94dcf, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@233fe9b6, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@358ee631, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@ec756bd, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@3c72f59f, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@60dcc9fe]
19:01:43.553 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
19:01:43.844 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.x.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Skipped XML bean definition file due to specified profiles [production] not matching: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
19:01:43.846 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@48aaecc3: startup date [Fri Apr 21 19:01:43 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
19:01:44.219 [main] INFO  c.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} inited
19:01:49.654 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
19:01:49.670 [main] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
19:01:49.766 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
19:01:49.768 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
19:01:49.799 [main] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
19:01:49.908 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
19:01:49.979 [main] INFO  o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl - HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
19:01:50.255 [main] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.4.1.Final
19:01:50.602 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
19:01:50.820 [main] INFO  o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
19:01:50.941 [main] INFO  o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
19:01:51.017 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@1e0fdb2f testClass = TdFinaacctMainDaoTest, testInstance = org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.syspara.TdFinaacctMainDaoTest@3c380bd8, testMethod = findFinaacctA@TdFinaacctMainDaoTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@6fc1020a testClass = TdFinaacctMainDaoTest, locations = '{classpath:/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@2c413ffc]; rollback [true]
19:01:51.147 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@1e0fdb2f testClass = TdFinaacctMainDaoTest, testInstance = org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.syspara.TdFinaacctMainDaoTest@3c380bd8, testMethod = findFinaacctA@TdFinaacctMainDaoTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@6fc1020a testClass = TdFinaacctMainDaoTest, locations = '{classpath:/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
19:01:51.153 [main] INFO  o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to proxy method [public final void org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
19:01:51.166 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@7f7b6639 testClass = JpaMappingTest, testInstance = org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest@16ac5d35, testMethod = allClassMapping@JpaMappingTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@18a19e testClass = JpaMappingTest, locations = '{classpath:/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@2c413ffc]; rollback [true]
19:01:51.167 [main] INFO  o.p.q.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest - first step
19:01:51.171 [main] INFO  o.p.q.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest - second step
19:01:51.171 [main] INFO  o.p.q.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest - third step
19:01:51.277 [main] INFO  o.p.q.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest - ok: TdFinaacctMain
19:01:51.277 [main] INFO  o.p.q.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest - fourth step
19:01:51.281 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.t.TransactionContext - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@7f7b6639 testClass = JpaMappingTest, testInstance = org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest@16ac5d35, testMethod = allClassMapping@JpaMappingTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@18a19e testClass = JpaMappingTest, locations = '{classpath:/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
19:01:51.283 [Thread-1] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@48aaecc3: startup date [Fri Apr 21 19:01:43 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
19:01:51.285 [Thread-1] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
19:01:51.290 [Thread-1] INFO  c.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} closed
```

2.when I use maven test, the console show these errors:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
19:03:22.107 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@31368b99, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@1725dc0f, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3911c2a7, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@4ac3c60d, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@4facf68f, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@76508ed1]
19:03:22.115 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@7714e963, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@20ce78ec, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@393671df, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@56620197, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@6eda5c9, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@55b7a4e0]
19:03:22.158 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
19:03:22.456 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.x.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Skipped XML bean definition file due to specified profiles [production] not matching: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
19:03:22.458 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@36bc55de: startup date [Fri Apr 21 19:03:22 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
19:03:22.754 [main] ERROR c.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} init error

19:03:22.756 [main] WARN  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
19:03:22.758 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3911c2a7] to prepare test instance [org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest@6986bbaf]
[INFO] Running org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest
19:03:22.767 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
19:03:22.818 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.x.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader - Skipped XML bean definition file due to specified profiles [production] not matching: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
19:03:22.820 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@6127a7e: startup date [Fri Apr 21 19:03:22 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
19:03:22.867 [main] ERROR c.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-2} init error
19:03:22.869 [main] WARN  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
19:03:22.872 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@393671df] to prepare test instance [org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.syspara.TdFinaacctMainDaoTest@5a9d6f02]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:55)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.createRequestAndRun(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.executeEager(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:323)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:143)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.createDriver(JdbcUtils.java:570)
    at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource.init(DruidDataSource.java:697)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.alibaba.druid.util.JdbcUtils.createDriver(JdbcUtils.java:568)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.113 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest
[ERROR] allClassMapping(org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.JpaMappingTest)  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

[INFO] Running org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.syspara.TdFinaacctMainDaoTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.syspara.TdFinaacctMainDaoTest
[ERROR] findFinaacctA(org.pbc.qzgk.tbdp.repository.syspara.TdFinaacctMainDaoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

Looks like that you have not added **db2jcc** in your maven dependencies. Please verify that by seeing the dependency tree:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

If your tests are running correctly in IDE. It's possible that you have added **db2jcc-*** jar manually in your classpath.

---

If you have specified the dependency in your maven dependencies and still get the error, it is possible that your application is heavy on the memory and maven is failing to load all classes into allocated heap. 
It can be resolved by increasing memory for surefire tests.

For that please refer to the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527789/specifying-maven-memory-parameter-without-setting-maven-opts-environment-variabl#answer-7528736).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        <argLine>-Xms$512m -Xmx$512m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```