# Increasing maven memory through pom file not working

Tags: java, maven, memory

I am getting StackOverflowError while building my project like -
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:625)
```

When i increased maven memory from terminal like export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xss1024m" It's working but i need to do same from pom file as build is failing in jenkins too.
I am using spring boot maven plugin, i tried many things like below but its not working. Please help.
Tried solutions in maven plugin -

```
 <jvmArguments>
                    -XX:PermSize=1024m
                    -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
                    -Xss1024m
                </jvmArguments>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
        <maxmem>512m</maxmem>
        <compilerArgument>-verbose -bootclasspath ${java.home}\lib\rt.jar</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Did you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527789/specifying-maven-memory-parameter-without-setting-maven-opts-environment-variabl

Answer (score 0):

Jankins builds a docker container based on your own docker file.

Inside that file you have to set maven options for its own JVM memory extention!