# While running a build inside Jenkins, I am getting "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError"

Tags: java, windows, maven, jenkins, build

2020-02-25 10:11:24.986+0000 [id=79]    INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Started maven-repo-cleanup
2020-02-25 10:11:25.004+0000 [id=79]    INFO    hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Finished maven-repo-cleanup. 14 ms
JVMDUMP039I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" at 2020/02/25 16:31:47 - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested System dump using 'C:\Users\KumariRupam\Documents\jenkins\core.20200225.163147.3284.0001.dmp' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I System dump written to C:\Users\KumariRupam\Documents\jenkins\core.20200225.163147.3284.0001.dmp
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Heap dump using 'C:\Users\KumariRupam\Documents\jenkins\heapdump.20200225.163147.3284.0002.phd' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Heap dump written to C:\Users\KumariRupam\Documents\jenkins\heapdump.20200225.163147.3284.0002.phd
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using 'C:\Users\KumariRupam\Documents\jenkins\javacore.20200225.163147.3284.0003.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to C:\Users\KumariRupam\Documents\jenkins\javacore.20200225.163147.3284.0003.txt
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Snap dump using 'C:\Users\KumariRupam\Documents\jenkins\Snap.20200225.163147.3284.0004.trc' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Snap dump written to C:\Users\KumariRupam\Documents\jenkins\Snap.20200225.163147.3284.0004.trc
JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".

Please help on same.

Comment: Does it work when you run the same build on your PC? You could try increasing the memory allocated when running the build in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the full context of your problem, but maybe increasing the allocated memory when you run the Maven build could help:

```
mvn clean install -DargLine="-Xmx1536m"
```

Here are some other examples on how to increase the allocated memory:

- [Strange Maven out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024270/strange-maven-out-of-memory-error)
- [Specifying Maven memory parameter without setting MAVEN_OPTS environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527789/specifying-maven-memory-parameter-without-setting-maven-opts-environment-variabl)

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins Windows setup comes with a 32-bit Java Runtime by default. Swapping that out with a 64-bit version and increasing the available memory through the `-Xmx` parameter did the trick for me. Jenkins machine is running stable for some months now.

**How to replace default 32-bit Java Runtime with a 64-bit one:**

- [Download OpenJDK 8 JRE](https://adoptopenjdk.net/upstream.html) for Windows x64

  - ⚠️ Note: Newer runtime may cause issues with some plugins. See [Java requirements](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/).
- Extract ZIP file to some folder, typically `C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8`
- Edit "jenkins.xml" to point to JRE8 (typically located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`):

  - `<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8\bin\java</executable>`

**How to increase available memory for Jenkins:**

- Edit "jenkins.xml" to increase argument of parameter `-Xmx` (typically located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`):

  - `<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx1536m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>`
  - This is just a sample of my configuration. In my experience 1,5 GiB memory works quite well. You may set `-Xmx` to a higher value if you still get crashes.