# Windows systemprofile Directory Showing Differently Based on User

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, msbuild, nuget

**Context:**

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins (2.223) build server (build using `msbuild` in this case) on Windows Server 2012 R2. Jenkins is set up as a service and runs as `Local System`.

**Problem:**

I've run into a problem where I can run a build script when RDP'd in as the Administrator user, but cannot run the same script through Jenkins. After some digging, I've found that the directory with the required build references (`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages`) is not being found by Jenkins. With a little more investigation, I've found that the directory `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile` appears to be inconsistent.

I can run the command `dir C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile` through my Administrator account and I get:

```
     Directory: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         3/11/2020   9:43 AM            .dotnet
d----         3/11/2020   2:27 PM            .nuget
d----          3/9/2020   1:49 PM            .ssh
d----         8/22/2013   6:36 AM            AppData
-a---          3/2/2020   3:41 PM     262144 ntuser.dat
```

I can run the same command (`dir C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`) through Jenkins, and I get:

```
    Directory: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
d----          3/9/2020   1:49 PM            .config                           
d----          3/6/2020   2:50 PM            .groovy                           
d----         8/22/2013   8:39 AM            AppData
```

I need the references within `...\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\` to be seen by Jenkins in order to complete the build (the references are put there by a `nuget restore` command run by the Jenkins service, so this seems reasonable to me). And to be honest, I'm not familiar with the concept of `dir` giving different results. I suspect Windows shenanigans, but I'm curious as to what's actually going on - why am I getting different results based on the user running the command?

**Additional Info:**

- I was able to get this working on my local Windows 10 desktop without any hassle. I do still get different results when executing the `dir` command as my user versus the Jenkins service, but they both happen to have the `systemprofile\.nuget\packages` directory available.
- On the 2012 server, my Admin user's $env:UserName and $env:ComputerName are `Administrator` and `WIN-64VG7CF1QK3` respectively. The Jenkin's local system $env:UserName and $env:ComputerName are both `WIN-64VG7CF1QK3`.

Comment: The symptom suggests that one process is a 64-bit process and the other a 32-bit one. Such processes see distinct directories as `C:\Windows\System32`, though you can technically access the respective other one as `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (the 32-bit dir. from a 64-bit process) and `C:\Windows\SysNative` (the 64-bit dir. from a 32-bit process).

Comment: I recommend to replace the default 32-bit Java runtime of Jenkins Windows version by 64-bit one to avoid these hassles. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398437/7571258).

Comment: @zett42 - thanks you two! Very helpful information. I'd upvote your comments but yet do I have that privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two comments on my question (**mklement0** and **zett42**) answered this pretty well, and using them I was able to better understand and resolve my issue.

It turns out that Jenkins does install 32-bit JRE by default - which ends up silently looking at `SysWOW64` instead of `System32` (but only during the `msbuild` command and not the `nuget restore` command?).

Anyways, the solution is to configure Jenkins to use a 64-bit JRE as suggested by **zett42**. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395701/while-running-a-build-inside-jenkins-i-am-getting-java-lang-outofmemoryerror/60398437#60398437).