# jenkins pipeline no permission to run a tool from system32 folder

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm running jenkins pipeline on a slave computer (slave run from agent command line - user with full admin privileges).
when trying to run a tool from system32 folder, it failes: The system cannot find the path specified.
if I copy the tool to c:\myfolder, it succeeds.

I've also tried to run msbuild - fails on post build regsvr32. but, when running the same command via computer's command line (not jenkins), it succeeds.

It looks like I have a problem with permissions but I do not know what is wrong. jenkins is running via command line with a user that have administrator permissions.

any ideas?

Comment: It's propably a 32/64-bit folder redirection issue. Is the slave running on a 32- or 64-bit JRE?

Comment: slave is running 32-bit JRE

Comment: Best solution is to [replace it with a 64-bit JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398437/7571258). Otherwise you are running into the [file system redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

Comment: I've replaced it to 64-bit JRE, still same errors.

Comment: What is shown under JENKINS_ROOT_URL/systemInfo for java.runtime.version and java.vm.name?

Comment: java runtimr version = 1.8.0_191-b12, java vm name = Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

Comment: java.vm.name for the slave computer is : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: Looks good for the slave. I wonder if it makes a difference that the master is running on a 32-bit JRE.